# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, IIS 10, Windows Server 2016, Web Deploy 5 Error: "Make sure that Web Deploy is installed"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-8, webdeploy-3.5

I installed IIS, Started Web Management Service, and Installed Web Platform Installer, checked the port, windows firewall is not enabled, shut down and started up, but still get the error that web deploy isn't installed when I try to publish with Web deploY in Visual Studio. What other configuration can I check to get the Web Deploy to complete?

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, IIS 10, Windows Server 2016, Web Deploy 5, ASP.net 4.6

Could not connect to the remote computer ("aspnet-dev"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not connect to the remote computer ("aspnet-dev"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

According to your error message, it seems you used the wrong server address. The web deploy could find the remote server("aspnet-dev").

Could you please tell me which server named "aspnet-dev"? On your current server or remote server?

If you just want to publish the web application to current server (VS is installed in the IIS server) ,I suggest you could firstly open the current IIS management console to make sure you have used the right server name and IIS web applicatio name.

Like below:

[image]

Then I suggest you could open the Web Platform Installer to check you have installed the web deploy.

[image]

If you want to publish the web application to remote server (VS isn't installed in the IIS server), I suggest you could use the server's IP address or domain instead of the server name like below:

```
https://yourhostname:8172/
```

Besides, I suggest you could refer to below article to generate the web deploy publish setting and use it to publish the web application to remote server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2017

More details about how to use web deploy to publish web application to remote server ,I suggest you could refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler

Comment: Thanks, that second link, ...configuring... is the one I've been reading. The full web server address is aspnet-dev.parkernet.edu. The sites on the aspnet-dev server are Default Web Site, and OnGrounds. How do I know if the server is current or remote? The server is not local, it is on a vmware. Visual Studio is not installed on the aspnet-dev server.

Comment: I have checked the aspnet-dev server and opened web platform installer 5.0, clicked the products tab. The products available are .net 3.5 for windows 8(not installed), .net 4.5 for windows 8 (installed), .net 4.5 extended with asp.net for windows 8 (installed). We are on .net 4.6. Could this mean the web installer will not be compatible?

Comment: It looks like the web platform installer doesn't complete installation. So, that must be the problem. I'll try file system deploy

Comment: Just adding a note for Web Deploy 3.6 - this doesn't install IIS Deployment Handler by default, so make sure you do a "Complete" or "Custom" install. This is required for Management Service Delegation rules (as described in the second link of this answer). If you don't install on first attempt, you will need to uninstall and reinstall from scratch. Using the "Modify" option to change later doesn't work.